# Is it true that $\langle u,w\rangle= \langle v,w\rangle$ implies $u = v$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $\Bbb R$.
>
> Is it true that $\langle u,w\rangle= \langle v,w\rangle$ implies $u = v$? Prove it or give a counter-example.

The above is exactly what my assignment demands. It does not state "for every $w$" belonging to vector space $V$.

I wonder what difference does it make to not state that "for every $v$" in $V$.

I was able to find a counter-example, let $u = (1,-1,0)$, $w = (0,-1,1)$ and $v = (1,1,1)$.

$\langle(1,-1,0), (1,1,1)\rangle = 0$

$\langle (0,-1,1), (1,1,1)\rangle = 0$

but $u \neq w$

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, your counterexample is sufficient. However, I think you've made a typo somewhere regarding $v$ and $w$.

Comment: What if the exercise would have stated that "for every v" in R?

Comment: I have answered this, assuming that you had made a typo in the middle.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Just corrected. I meant "for every w".

Comment: I figured, my answer answers assuming that (albeit the roles of $v$ and $w$ are swapped). Let me know if that isn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noted, $\langle u, v\rangle = \langle w, v\rangle$ is not sufficient to conclude $u = w$. In fact, what you do get is that $$\langle u - w, v\rangle = 0.$$
That is, $u - w$ is orthogonal to $v$. Now, if you are given that the above is true for *all* $v \in V$, then you can put $v = u - w$ to get $$\langle u - w, u - w\rangle = 0.$$
By the positive-definiteness of inner product, this implies that $u - w = 0$ or $u = w$, as desired.